# export javascript alert box message to php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I'm really stuck here, I know it is a basic question but I really need some help.

I have a radio box  in html which I have to following code to get show which radio box is selected.

```
<script>
$( "input" ).on( "click", function() {
alert($( "input:checked" ).val() + "" );



 });</script>
```

This works as expected, what I would like to do now is when the radio box is selected still display the alert but also export the alert contents to a php file, I have tried all sorts of methods and have come up short, any help would be greatly appreciated.

I tried with ajax with the following code, I have no idea where it is going wrong

```
$( "input" ).on( "click", function() {

$.ajax({ //Process the form using $.ajax()
        type      : 'POST', //Method type
        url       : 'process.php', //Your form processing file URL
        data      : $( "input:checked" ).val() + "Entered";   

        success   : alert($( "input:checked" ).val() + "Entered" );
    });


});</script>
```

Comment: You might want to see [jQuery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Comment: Thanks, I am trying with ajax, I really have no idea. Thanks anyway

Comment: Insted of the thread suggested I would recommend this one for your case http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5004233/jquery-ajax-post-example-with-php